# Problem with Database for survey Questionnaires

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Bellow I am showing a sample survey question for woman. I need your help to creating a Database.

[image]

Description:

- Top part of the survey Questions are Project Code, Name... etc which
  is understandable.

  2. Questions have some groups with No and Name, Here I am showing 2 groups.
  3. Each group have some questions.
  4. Each question has 4 columns i.e No, Questions, Response and Skip.
  5. Question 1.01 to 1.04: Data entry operator will input these data and Skip is Blank.
  6. Question 1.05 Operator will input one number from 1 to 4.
  7. If Question 1.05 answer is 1 then it will Skip question 1.06 to 1.08 and answer 2.01 no question. Skip column is showing Quesion no.
  8. If Question 1.05 answer is 4 then Operator will type some text data.
  9. Hard part of the Question, No 2.02, Inside this question there is another A to E sub question and their answer will be 1 or 2.
     10.Question 2.02, sub part no D. Operator will input 1 or 2 and also input some text.

Hope I can make you understand for the survey. I need to create a database for this survey questions. Hope I can get your expart opinion.
Thanks in advance!

I did some homework and I am attaching the db diagram but it is not suitable for Qs. no 2.02. I need a better solution. 
[image]